# How to bind with property to check box generated by comobo box in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one combo box with check box whose xaml looks like this:

```
<ComboBox Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,7,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox Name="ckabc" Content="{Binding}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=SetSelectAllCommand}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

and in view model code is like this:

```
public List<string> Names
{
    get { return names; }
    set
    {
        names = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Names"));
    }
}
```

I need this value on mainform so I did this part in constructor :

```
Names = new List<string> { "Not Connected", "Quality", "Light", 
               "Connected", " Sensor", "Detected", "Unusable", "Change" };
this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Names"));
```

So Now combo box is coming with checkbox. I have to bind the checkbox with property which is calling my API

please tell me how can i do this?

e.g. all the text of combo box is property

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but a checkbox inside a combobox seems strange to me. Wouldn't a listbox with checkboxes be better? From a ComboBox, the user would expect so select only one value.

Comment: The use case is definitely weird.

Comment: You already have `Command` binded to checkBox. Why you want to bind to other property? Set the property from command handler.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of *why* you want to do this, there is indeed a technique for it. By taking advantage of the `ElementName` attribute, you can "jump" out of a template into the root data context.

```
<Window Name="Root">   
    <ComboBox Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,7,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
       <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox Name="ckabc" Content="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.MySpecialProperty}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>   
</Window>
```

That being said, `CheckBox` in a `ComboBox` does sound odd, you may want to reconsider.

Comment: I have combobox with checkbox(6 checkbox).I have to bind this check box with property. It means I have total 6 property. When User Check to checkbox on that It should call to corresponding property.I think you got my point now.

Comment: @user2932395 Ok, so each one is bound separately (as in my example), or the combobox items source is bound, and you bind to a property on the bound item. Does that make sense? Is there an additional question here?